# Can someone help me with this java code? Loop error

Tags: java

I am newish to programming and am trying to make a higher or lower game, but am having a few problems. First, I want the program  to loop when the card is guessed right i.e. the lower option is chosen and it is lower. However it crashes after the second loop and nothing happens. When it is game over, I would and chose to play again, nothing happens. if someone could help me solve these problems it would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
import
```

Comment: Please edit to set a relevant title.

Comment: Please check out the [help], [tour], and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to get an introduction to how this site works and how to ask better questions and thereby get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int card = 0;
    int cardNext;

    String userResponse;
    String userPlayAgain;
    boolean userGuessedRight = true;

    do {
        do {
            Random randomNumbers = new Random();
            card = randomNumbers.nextInt(13 - 1 + 1) + 1;
            System.out.println("Card is " + card);

            System.out.print("Higher or Lower?");
            cardNext = randomNumbers.nextInt(13) + 1;
            userResponse = scan.next();
            userGuessedRight = (userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("H") && cardNext >= card)
                    || (userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("L") && cardNext <= card);

            if (userGuessedRight) {
                System.out.println("Card is " + cardNext);
                System.out.print("Higher or Lower?");
                userResponse = scan.next();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } while (userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("H") && cardNext < card || userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("L") && cardNext > card);
        System.out.println("Card is " + cardNext);
        System.out.println("Card is higher/lower you lose – play again? Y/N : ");
        userPlayAgain = scan.next();
    } while (userPlayAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

    do {
        if (userPlayAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))

        {
            System.out.print("Thank You.");
            break;
        }

    } while (!userPlayAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

    scan.close();
}
```

**Edit**

Here is the output :
[image: The output of the program]

Comment: Hey, with this one, sometimes it accepts the card even though it's wrong

Comment: It depend on your logic, did you tried this "<" instead of "<=" or ">" instead of ">="

Comment: Ok, thanks all working now. There's one problem, can I add a condition somewhere that states "the card is HIGHER / LOWER, you lose"? At the moment it only says card is lower, because of the condition

Comment: @the_no_1 Simply where the `System.out.println("Card is lower you lose – play again? Y/N : ");` is add `if(cardNext < card) System.out.println("Card is lower you lose – play again? Y/N : "); else System.out.println("Card is higher you lose – play again? Y/N : ");`  Please accept Anarki's answer as he answered your original question.